# How to change the position of calendar that pops up while using Datefield in gxt?

Tags: gwt, gxt

I want to know is there anyway to change the position of calendar that pops up when we click the datefield in gxt ? my calendar is popping out somewhere outside instead of popping up near the date field.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using setPosition(x, y) to move your calendar, or you can try using alignTo method, something like this:

```
DatePicker dp = new DatePicker();
dp.setPosition(100, 100);
dp.getElement().alignTo(yourTextField.getElement(), new AnchorAlignment(Anchor.BOTTOM), null);
```

Comment: I used DateField as my date object

DateField dateFrom = new DateField();     
dateFrom.setDate(new Date());
FieldLabel dtf = new FieldLabel(dateFrom, DATE FROM );

Comment: Could you update your post with your code snippet? I can help you better when you provide me enough information of what have you done, and what you want to achieve. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
My code is a bit lengthier so i'm just posting the part of code where i used Date.



final Date currentDate = new Date();
        dateFrom = new DateField();
        dateFrom.setValue(currentDate);
        dateFrom.setEditable(false);
        dateFrom.setWidth(90);
        final FieldLabel fldf = new FieldLabel(dateFrom, messages.dateFrom());
        fldf.setLabelWidth(70);
        dateFrom.addParseErrorHandler(new ParseErrorHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onParseError(ParseErrorEvent event) {
                Info.display(messages.parseError(), event.getErrorValue()
                        + messages.parseDateError());
            }
        });


final HorizontalLayoutContainer hc1 = new HorizontalLayoutContainer();
hc1.insert(fldf, 1, new HorizontalLayoutData(-1, 1, new Margins(20,0,0));


        final VerticalLayoutContainer vlc = new VerticalLayoutContainer();


        vlc.insert(oneMessageLabel, 0);
        vlc.insert(twoMessageLabel, 1);
        vlc.insert(threeMessageLabel, 2);
        vlc.insert(hc1, 3);


        final FramedPanel fpSearch = new FramedPanel();
        fpSearch.setHeadingText("Search");
        fpSearch.setPixelSize(995,160);
        fpSearch.setStyleName("xframedPanelDash");

        fpSearch.add(vlc);




        FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
        formPanel.add(fpSearch);

        final HorizontalLayoutContainer hcErrorPanel = new HorizontalLayoutContainer();
        hcErrorPanel.insert(formPanel, 0, new HorizontalLayoutData(-1, 1,
                new Margin(70,0,0,10));

        vlc = new VerticalLayoutContainer();
        vlc.setScrollMode(ScrollMode.AUTO);
        vlc.add(hcErrorReportPanel);

        initWidget(vlc);
```